# Hydro move_base/tf2 extrapolation error into the future errror

Tags: navigation, ros-hydro, tf2, local-planner, global-planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

We are using Hyrdo's move_base and we continue to get an extrapolation error into the future. I believe this is causing our robot to stop and start during a traverse.

In looking the ROS source code it appears that the lookupTransform in navigation/base_local_planner/src/goal_functions.cpp line 110 in transformGlobalPlan is returning the error. We are using the dwa_local_planner. We are publishing transforms at 20hz from a separate node. The parameters to tf.lookupTransform are  global_frame = "local" and the plan_pose.header.frame_id = "global", and the plan_pose.header.stamp comes from the generating the gloabl plan. I think the bug is coming from tf2/src/buffer_core.cpp in WalkToTopParent(). I still need to do more debugging to find the exact problem. I've turned the debug information on for move_base so I'm including a snippet of it, and the console log below. Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

```
[DEBUG] [1386166204.375994679]: The action server has received a new goal request
[DEBUG] [1386166204.376260355]: A new goal has been recieved by the single goal action server
[DEBUG] [1386166204.376656845]: Accepting a new goal
[DEBUG] [1386166204.376895493]: Accepting goal, id: /waypoint_management_node-1-1386166204.372833387, stamp: 1386166204.37
[DEBUG] [1386166204.377491239]: Publishing feedback for goal, id: /waypoint_management_node-1-1386166204.372833387, stamp: 1386166204.37
[DEBUG] [1386166204.377705512]: Publishing feedback for goal with id: /waypoint_management_node-1-1386166204.372833387 and stamp: 1386166204.37
[DEBUG] [1386166204.378025665]: Planning...
[DEBUG] [1386166204.378168840]: Waiting for plan, in the planning state.
[DEBUG] [1386166204.378332478]: Full control cycle time: 0.000979315

[DEBUG] [1386166204.455307564]: Got Plan with 49 points!
[DEBUG] [1386166204.457263957]: Generated a plan from the base_global_planner
[DEBUG] [1386166204.458307175]: Planner thread is suspending
[DEBUG] [1386166204.477544259]: Publishing feedback for goal, id: /waypoint_management_node-1-1386166204.372833387, stamp: 1386166204.37
[DEBUG] [1386166204.477708316]: Publishing feedback for goal with id: /waypoint_management_node-1-1386166204.372833387 and stamp: 1386166204.37
[DEBUG] [1386166204.477914069]: Got a new plan...swap pointers
[DEBUG] [1386166204.478065066]: pointers swapped!
[ INFO] [1386166204.478229751]: Got new plan
[DEBUG] [1386166204.478925371]: In controlling state.
[DEBUG] [1386166204.515009849]: Got a valid command from the local planner: 0.500, 0.000, 2.000
[DEBUG] [1386166204.516475469]: Full control cycle time: 0.037907056

[DEBUG] [1386166204.578542367]: Publishing feedback for goal, id: /waypoint_management_node-1-1386166204.372833387, stamp: 1386166204.37
[DEBUG] [1386166204.579298889]: Publishing feedback for goal with id: /waypoint_management_node-1-1386166204.372833387 and stamp: 1386166204.37
[DEBUG] [1386166204.580845315]: In controlling state.
[DEBUG] [1386166204.609181880]: Got a valid command from the local planner: 0.500, 0.000, 2.000
[DEBUG] [1386166204.610400540]: Full control cycle time: 0.031062960

[DEBUG] [1386166204.677557610]: Publishing feedback for goal, id: /waypoint_management_node-1-1386166204.372833387, stamp: 1386166204.37
[DEBUG] [1386166204.677725508]: Publishing feedback for goal with id: /waypoint_management_node-1-1386166204.372833387 and stamp: 1386166204.37
[DEBUG] [1386166204.677947673]: In controlling state.
[DEBUG] [1386166204.704567051]: Got a valid command from the local planner: 0.500, 0.000, 2.000
[DEBUG] [1386166204.705445516]: Full control cycle time: 0.027409982

[DEBUG] [1386166204.777927638]: Publishing feedback for goal, id: /waypoint_management_node-1-1386166204.372833387, stamp: 1386166204.37
[DEBUG] [1386166204.779469173]: Publishing feedback for goal with id: /waypoint_management_node-1-1386166204.372833387 and stamp: 1386166204.37
[DEBUG] [1386166204.790713341]: In controlling state.
[ WARN] [1386166204.799236284]: Could not transform the global plan to the frame of the controller
[DEBUG] [1386166204.802767947]: The local planner could not find a valid plan.
[DEBUG] [1386166204.804277915]: Planning...
[DEBUG] [1386166204.806757562]: Full control cycle time: 0.029080164

[DEBUG] [1386166204.877208489]: Got Plan with 49 points!
[DEBUG] [1386166204.878977430]: Publishing feedback for goal, id: /waypoint_management_node-1-1386166204.372833387, stamp: 1386166204.37
[DEBUG] [1386166204.879146725]: Publishing feedback for goal with id: /waypoint_management_node-1-1386166204.372833387 and stamp: 1386166204.37
[DEBUG] [1386166204.879352897]: Waiting for plan, in the planning state.
[DEBUG] [1386166204.879506199]: Full control cycle time: 0.002110815

[DEBUG] [1386166204.884773975]: Generated a plan from the base_global_planner
[DEBUG] [1386166204.886034821]: Planner thread is suspending
[DEBUG] [1386166204.977587453]: Publishing feedback for goal, id: /waypoint_management_node-1-1386166204.372833387, stamp: 1386166204.37
[DEBUG] [1386166204.977886654]: Publishing feedback for goal with id: /waypoint_management_node-1-1386166204.372833387 and stamp: 1386166204.37
[DEBUG] [1386166204.978173771]: Got a new plan...swap pointers
[DEBUG] [1386166204.978476044]: pointers swapped!
[ INFO] [1386166204.978669994]: Got new plan
[DEBUG] [1386166204.978856819]: In controlling state.
[DEBUG] [1386166205.017628512]: Got a valid command from the local planner: 0.448, 0.000, 1.812
[DEBUG] [1386166205.018593509]: Full control cycle time: 0.040484062

[DEBUG] [1386166205.077536129]: Publishing feedback for goal, id: /waypoint_management_node-1-1386166204.372833387, stamp: 1386166204.37
[DEBUG] [1386166205.077705983]: Publishing feedback for goal with id: /waypoint_management_node-1-1386166204.372833387 and stamp: 1386166204.37
[DEBUG] [1386166205.077902098]: In controlling state.
[DEBUG] [1386166205.117635921]: Got a valid command from the local planner: 0.266, 0.000, 2.063
[DEBUG] [1386166205.118555451]: Full control cycle time: 0.040495094

[DEBUG] [1386166205.177749432]: Publishing feedback for goal, id: /waypoint_management_node-1-1386166204.372833387, stamp: 1386166204.37
[DEBUG] [1386166205.179715326]: Publishing feedback for goal with id: /waypoint_management_node-1-1386166204.372833387 and stamp: 1386166204.37
[DEBUG] [1386166205.185337546]: In controlling state.
[DEBUG] [1386166205.230841448]: Got a valid command from the local planner: 0.397, 0.000, 2.072
[DEBUG] [1386166205.232476503]: Full control cycle time: 0.054954404

[DEBUG] [1386166205.281725014]: Publishing feedback for goal, id: /waypoint_management_node-1-1386166204.372833387, stamp: 1386166204.37
[DEBUG] [1386166205.282137427]: Publishing feedback for goal with id: /waypoint_management_node-1-1386166204.372833387 and stamp: 1386166204.37
[DEBUG] [1386166205.285275257]: In controlling state.
[DEBUG] [1386166205.324930439]: Got a valid command from the local planner: 0.333, 0.000, 1.935
[DEBUG] [1386166205.325334959]: Full control cycle time: 0.043936313

[DEBUG] [1386166205.377754753]: Publishing feedback for goal, id: /waypoint_management_node-1-1386166204.372833387, stamp: 1386166204.37
[DEBUG] [1386166205.400018545]: Publishing feedback for goal with id: /waypoint_management_node-1-1386166204.372833387 and stamp: 1386166204.37
[DEBUG] [1386166205.403311982]: In controlling state.
[DEBUG] [1386166205.434306499]: Got a valid command from the local planner: 0.500, 0.000, 1.819
[DEBUG] [1386166205.434547731]: Full control cycle time: 0.057089105

[DEBUG] [1386166205.478460574]: Publishing feedback for goal, id: /waypoint_management_node-1-1386166204.372833387, stamp: 1386166204.37
[DEBUG] [1386166205.480680196]: Publishing feedback for goal with id: /waypoint_management_node-1-1386166204.372833387 and stamp: 1386166204.37
[DEBUG] [1386166205.487263089]: In controlling state.
[DEBUG] [1386166205.526915895]: Got a valid command from the local planner: 0.500, 0.000, 1.819
[DEBUG] [1386166205.529046611]: Full control cycle time: 0.050830132

[DEBUG] [1386166205.577675708]: Publishing feedback for goal, id: /waypoint_management_node-1-1386166204.372833387, stamp: 1386166204.37
[DEBUG] [1386166205.578052571]: Publishing feedback for goal with id: /waypoint_management_node-1-1386166204.372833387 and stamp: 1386166204.37
[DEBUG] [1386166205.581128380]: In controlling state.
[DEBUG] [1386166205.637572985]: Got a valid command from the local planner: 0.195, 0.000, -2.543
[DEBUG] [1386166205.639640568]: Full control cycle time: 0.062151475

[DEBUG] [1386166205.677513544]: Publishing feedback for goal, id: /waypoint_management_node-1-1386166204.372833387, stamp: 1386166204.37
[DEBUG] [1386166205.678263639]: Publishing feedback for goal with id: /waypoint_management_node-1-1386166204.372833387 and stamp: 1386166204.37
[DEBUG] [1386166205.681451196]: In controlling state.
[DEBUG] [1386166205.727866873]: Got a valid command from the local planner: 0.500, 0.000, -3.059
[DEBUG] [1386166205.730029437]: Full control cycle time: 0.052604942

[DEBUG] [1386166205.780110809]: Publishing feedback for goal, id: /waypoint_management_node-1-1386166204.372833387, stamp: 1386166204.37
[DEBUG] [1386166205.794376448]: Publishing feedback for goal with id: /waypoint_management_node-1-1386166204.372833387 and stamp: 1386166204.37
[DEBUG] [1386166205.796889897]: In controlling state.
[DEBUG] [1386166205.830207541]: Got a valid command from the local planner: 0.152, 0.000, -2.778
[DEBUG] [1386166205.831599686]: Full control cycle time: 0.050707284

[DEBUG] [1386166205.877740193]: Publishing feedback for goal, id: /waypoint_management_node-1-1386166204.372833387, stamp: 1386166204.37
[DEBUG] [1386166205.879729759]: Publishing feedback for goal with id: /waypoint_management_node-1-1386166204.372833387 and stamp: 1386166204.37
[DEBUG] [1386166205.884120613]: In controlling state.
[DEBUG] [1386166205.937035721]: Got a valid command from the local planner: 0.038, 0.000, -2.498
[DEBUG] [1386166205.937388280]: Full control cycle time: 0.059935484

[DEBUG] [1386166205.977746411]: Publishing feedback for goal, id: /waypoint_management_node-1-1386166204.372833387, stamp: 1386166204.37
[DEBUG] [1386166205.978260444]: Publishing feedback for goal with id: /waypoint_management_node-1-1386166204.372833387 and stamp: 1386166204.37
[DEBUG] [1386166205.978659377]: In controlling state.
[DEBUG] [1386166206.023969471]: Got a valid command from the local planner: 0.108, 0.000, -2.564
[DEBUG] [1386166206.025671223]: Full control cycle time: 0.048180431

[DEBUG] [1386166206.077568603]: Publishing feedback for goal, id: /waypoint_management_node-1-1386166204.372833387, stamp: 1386166204.37
[DEBUG] [1386166206.079011246]: Publishing feedback for goal with id: /waypoint_management_node-1-1386166204.372833387 and stamp: 1386166204.37
[DEBUG] [1386166206.090116010]: In controlling state.
[DEBUG] [1386166206.119367495]: Got a valid command from the local planner: -0.130, 0.000, 1.822
[DEBUG] [1386166206.120285489]: Full control cycle time: 0.042222758

[DEBUG] [1386166206.177683082]: Publishing feedback for goal, id: /waypoint_management_node-1-1386166204.372833387, stamp: 1386166204.37
[DEBUG] [1386166206.182863279]: Publishing feedback for goal with id: /waypoint_management_node-1-1386166204.372833387 and stamp: 1386166204.37
[DEBUG] [1386166206.197095536]: In controlling state.
[DEBUG] [1386166206.212940568]: Got a valid command from the local planner: -0.198, 0.000, 1.442
[DEBUG] [1386166206.214603070]: Full control cycle time: 0.035785557

[DEBUG] [1386166206.277678969]: Publishing feedback for goal, id: /waypoint_management_node-1-1386166204.372833387, stamp: 1386166204.37
[DEBUG] [1386166206.284374863]: Publishing feedback for goal with id: /waypoint_management_node-1-1386166204.372833387 and stamp: 1386166204.37
[DEBUG] [1386166206.296676079]: In controlling state.
[DEBUG] [1386166206.319835447]: Got a valid command from the local planner: 0.500, 0.000, -1.653
[DEBUG] [1386166206.321370140]: Full control cycle time: 0.042692021

[DEBUG] [1386166206.377575259]: Publishing feedback for goal, id: /waypoint_management_node-1-1386166204.372833387, stamp: 1386166204.37
[DEBUG] [1386166206.377766834]: Publishing feedback for goal with id: /waypoint_management_node-1-1386166204.372833387 and stamp: 1386166204.37
[DEBUG] [1386166206.378720587]: In controlling state.
[DEBUG] [1386166206.413027463]: Got a valid command from the local planner: 0.500, 0.000, -1.745
[DEBUG] [1386166206.414450061]: Full control cycle time: 0.035884731

[DEBUG] [1386166206.477536506]: Publishing feedback for goal, id: /waypoint_management_node-1-1386166204.372833387, stamp: 1386166204.37
[DEBUG] [1386166206.477800296]: Publishing feedback for goal with id: /waypoint_management_node-1-1386166204.372833387 and stamp: 1386166204.37
[DEBUG] [1386166206.477999414]: In controlling state.
[DEBUG] [1386166206.512341491]: Got a valid command from the local planner: 0.500, 0.000, -1.800
[DEBUG] [1386166206.515639114]: Full control cycle time: 0.037860399

[DEBUG] [1386166206.577530785]: Publishing feedback for goal, id: /waypoint_management_node-1-1386166204.372833387, stamp: 1386166204.37
[DEBUG] [1386166206.577707902]: Publishing feedback for goal with id: /waypoint_management_node-1-1386166204.372833387 and stamp: 1386166204.37
[DEBUG] [1386166206.578704469]: In controlling state.
[DEBUG] [1386166206.619075733]: Got a valid command from the local planner: 0.500, 0.000, -1.625
[DEBUG] [1386166206.619376330]: Full control cycle time: 0.041916294

[DEBUG] [1386166206.678381670]: Publishing feedback for goal, id: /waypoint_management_node-1-1386166204.372833387, stamp: 1386166204.37
[DEBUG] [1386166206.678848279]: Publishing feedback for goal with id: /waypoint_management_node-1-1386166204.372833387 and stamp: 1386166204.37
[DEBUG] [1386166206.679309161]: In controlling state.
[DEBUG] [1386166206.717656704]: Got a valid command from the local planner: 0.500, 0.000, -1.331
[DEBUG] [1386166206.717989707]: Full control cycle time: 0.039929237

[DEBUG] [1386166206.777679981]: Publishing feedback for goal, id: /waypoint_management_node-1-1386166204.372833387, stamp: 1386166204.37
[DEBUG] [1386166206.778062151]: Publishing feedback for goal with id: /waypoint_management_node-1-1386166204.372833387 and stamp: 1386166204.37
[DEBUG] [1386166206.785956171]: In controlling state.
[DEBUG] [1386166206.828150085]: Got a valid command from the local planner: 0.500, 0.000, -1.237
[DEBUG] [1386166206.829181222]: Full control cycle time: 0.050999570

[DEBUG] [1386166206.877526477]: Publishing feedback for goal, id: /waypoint_management_node-1-1386166204.372833387, stamp: 1386166204.37
[DEBUG] [1386166206.878493218]: Publishing feedback for goal with id: /waypoint_management_node-1-1386166204.372833387 and stamp: 1386166204.37
[DEBUG] [1386166206.880053119]: In controlling state.
[DEBUG] [1386166206.915862917]: Got a valid command from the local planner: 0.500, 0.000, -1.524
[DEBUG] [1386166206.916878689]: Full control cycle time: 0.039424008

[DEBUG] [1386166206.978204362]: Publishing feedback for goal, id: /waypoint_management_node-1-1386166204.372833387, stamp: 1386166204.37
[DEBUG] [1386166206.979811901]: Publishing feedback for goal with id: /waypoint_management_node-1-1386166204.372833387 and stamp: 1386166204.37
[DEBUG] [1386166206.992529931]: In controlling state.
[DEBUG] [1386166207.028332035]: Got a valid command from the local planner: 0.500, 0.000, -2.383
[DEBUG] [1386166207.029387966]: Full control cycle time: 0.050805903

[DEBUG] [1386166207.077680283]: Publishing feedback for goal, id: /waypoint_management_node-1-1386166204.372833387, stamp: 1386166204.37
[DEBUG] [1386166207.078072371]: Publishing feedback for goal with id: /waypoint_management_node-1-1386166204.372833387 and stamp: 1386166204.37
[DEBUG] [1386166207.093392754]: In controlling state.
[ WARN] [1386166207.099315434]: Could not transform the global plan to the frame of the controller
[DEBUG] [1386166207.101504469]: The local planner could not find a valid plan.
[DEBUG] [1386166207.101739345]: Planning...
[DEBUG] [1386166207.107393974]: Full control cycle time: 0.029821387

[DEBUG] [1386166207.167421509]: Got Plan with 54 points!
[DEBUG] [1386166207.167596461]: Generated a plan from the base_global_planner
[DEBUG] [1386166207.167711420]: Planner thread is suspending
[DEBUG] [1386166207.177533339]: Publishing feedback for goal, id: /waypoint_management_node-1-1386166204.372833387, stamp: 1386166204.37
[DEBUG] [1386166207.177852095]: Publishing feedback for goal with id: /waypoint_management_node-1-1386166204.372833387 and stamp: 1386166204.37
[DEBUG] [1386166207.178045695]: Got a new plan...swap pointers
[DEBUG] [1386166207.178153530]: pointers swapped!
[ INFO] [1386166207.178254660]: Got new plan
[DEBUG] [1386166207.178382330]: In controlling state.
[DEBUG] [1386166207.218677960]: Got a valid command from the local planner: 0.500, 0.000, -2.453
[DEBUG] [1386166207.219088626]: Full control cycle time: 0.041611440

[DEBUG] [1386166207.277684346]: Publishing feedback for goal, id: /waypoint_management_node-1-1386166204.372833387, stamp: 1386166204.37
[DEBUG] [1386166207.278083839]: Publishing feedback for goal with id: /waypoint_management_node-1-1386166204.372833387 and stamp: 1386166204.37
[DEBUG] [1386166207.278807744]: In controlling state.
[DEBUG] [1386166207.325121383]: Got a valid command from the local planner: 0.500, 0.000, -2.205
[DEBUG] [1386166207.328377944]: Full control cycle time: 0.050748982
```

FROM CONSOLE:

```
[ERROR] [1386166204.794600431]: Extrapolation Error: Lookup would require extrapolation into the future.  Requested time 1386166204.760608679 but the latest data is at time 1386166204.681006934, when looking up transform from frame [local] to frame [global]

[ERROR] [1386166204.798496177]: Global Frame: local Plan Frame size 49: global

[ERROR] [1386166204.801676467]: Could not get local plan
[ERROR] [1386166207.094102621]: Extrapolation Error: Lookup would require extrapolation into the future.  Requested time 1386166207.060895396 but the latest data is at time 1386166206.992936965, when looking up transform from frame [local] to frame [global]

[ERROR] [1386166207.098096425]: Global Frame: local Plan Frame size 49: global

[ERROR] [1386166207.101307796]: Could not get local plan
[ERROR] [1386166208.600555921]: Extrapolation Error: Lookup would require extrapolation into the future.  Requested time 1386166208.560276359 but the latest data is at time 1386166208.477921333, when looking up transform from frame [local] to frame [global]

[ERROR] [1386166208.605807498]: Global Frame: local Plan Frame size 54: global

[ERROR] [1386166208.608851947]: Could not get local plan
[ERROR] [1386166210.296415706]: Extrapolation Error: Lookup would require extrapolation into the future.  Requested time 1386166210.259930623 but the latest data is at time 1386166210.184060640, when looking up transform from frame [local] to frame [global]

[ERROR] [1386166210.299559126]: Global Frame: local Plan Frame size 53: global

[ERROR] [1386166210.305595433]: Could not get local plan
[ERROR] [1386166211.594665718]: Extrapolation Error: Lookup would require extrapolation into the future.  Requested time 1386166211.560573392 but the latest data is at time 1386166211.480167357, when looking up transform from frame [local] to frame [global]

[ERROR] [1386166211.597373393]: Global Frame: local Plan Frame size 56: global

[ERROR] [1386166211.601120168]: Could not get local plan
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/106996/hydro-move_base/tf2-extrapolation-error-into-the-future-errror/) by [robotiqsguy](https://answers.ros.org/users/9521/robotiqsguy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2013-12-04

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Well, the code requests transformPose with time t_b of the latest base pose. If you publish at different places of your node, time t_g of global would e.g. have a slightly earlier timestamp - and tf must fail. Same thing if one of the other tf-messages has not been received yet. Unless you enable extrapolation, this is how tf(2) should behave.
In amcl - which would typically publish the map->odom or world->local transform - they timestamp the transform with 0.2s in the future. Maybe that's also a solution for you?

---

Originally posted by [Niccer](https://answers.ros.org/users/9566/niccer/) with karma: 46 on 2013-12-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [robotiqsguy](https://answers.ros.org/users/9521/robotiqsguy/) on 2013-12-12**:
We timestamp our local and global transforms with the same time. They are being published in the same sendTransform since we use a vector of transforms. I assume upon receiving a vector that access to tf is locked, so if one transform is in tf the other one would be too. Transforms are sent at 20Hz.

**Comment by [Niccer](https://answers.ros.org/users/9566/niccer/) on 2013-12-17**:
Maybe it helps to dump all the frames that are in your tf instance? There is the getFrames() method - not sure if it prints the timestamps though.

**Comment by [robotiqsguy](https://answers.ros.org/users/9521/robotiqsguy/) on 2013-12-17**:
HI Niccer, I'm noobie to ROS, so please keep the suggestions coming. This is an intermittent problem. After the change I made to send a vector of Transforms the problem happens much less. But it still happens. I wish there were some good tools for online debugging of TF2 problems.

**Comment by [robotiqsguy](https://answers.ros.org/users/9521/robotiqsguy/) on 2013-12-17**:
To debug this problem I was thinking of pushing values on to the error_string. That way it would only get printed when an error happens.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-12-17**:
There are debugging tutorials here: http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials/Debugging%20tf%20problems and feel free to put debugging code in whereever you need.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

there are many questions here about that error in different scenarios. I am using slam_karto and groovy, but the code in goal_functions.cpp has not changed much.

I also found that the exception is thrown in navigation/base_local_planner/src/goal_functions.cpp:transformGlobalPlan() - yet for me, tf.lookupTransform (line 110) is ok, but tf.transformPose (line 116) fails. My tf-tree is /map -> /odom -> /base_footprint. /odom is published with an average delay of 90ms, while /base_footprint has a delay of 35ms. Debugging the code shows that tf.transformPose is requested to transform the pose to /map at now()-35ms. That fails, since the /odom transformation is older, and tf apparently does not extrapolate so far into the future.

My solution was to change the tf.transformPose call, such that it takes the most recent time:
tf.transformPose(plan_pose.header.frame_id, ros::Time(0), global_pose, global_pose.frame_id_, robot_pose);

While this works, I wonder how things should behave in the original code. Are delays between the different frames not accepted? Or does the extrapolation usually work, for whatever reason? Maybe someone who runs move_base successfully can comment on that.

@robotiqsguy: Could you verify where exactly the exception is triggered in your case? Also, what delays do you see for your frames, if you run rosrun tf tf_monitor?

Best Regards!

---

Originally posted by [Niccer](https://answers.ros.org/users/9566/niccer/) with karma: 46 on 2013-12-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1